# How does the nlrob function from the robustbase package in R calculate the standard errors of the parameter estimates?

Tags: r, regression, robust

I would like to estimate the parameters and standard errors of the parameters of a nonlinear model with the M-Estimator in R. For that reason I use the function `nlrob()` from the `robustbase` package. When I use the summary() function to check the results of `nlrob()`, it shows standard errors of the parameters. Unfortunately, I cannot find the procedure used to calculate these standard errors in the documentation.

How does `nlrob()` estimate the standard errors of the parameter estimates? Thanks in advance!

Comment: start by digging into `robustbase:::summary.nlrob` ... and `?vcov.nlrob` ... it looks like it uses the Hessian from the optimization ... ?

Comment: This is the function used for in the summary to calculate the standard errors: `.vcov.m(object, Scale = sc, resid.sc = as.vector(object$residuals)/sc)` How can I find the source code of this function?

Comment: `robustbase:::.vcov.m`.  But I think you'll discover that the actual computation of interest is done within `nlrob`: look at the source code and search for `asCov`, which will lead you to `nls`; `nls` objects have an `$m$Rmat()` function, which I think will contain the Hessian ...